# How to get MultiMarkDown to view tables in Sublime Text 2 OSX

Tags: editor, sublimetext2, markdown, sublimetext, multimarkdown

I am trying to avoid using inline HTML to get tables working in my MD file.   I have [Markdown Preview](https://github.com/revolunet/sublimetext-markdown-preview) and [Table Editor](https://github.com/vkocubinsky/SublimeTableEditor) installed via the package installer, and [multimarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/install/) installed via [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/), but I can't get the following text to display as a table:

```
| Left align adsf  | Right align | Center align |
| :--------------- | ----------: | :----------: |
| This             |        This |     This     |
| column           |      column |    column    |
| will             |        will |     will     |
| be               |          be |      be      |
| left             |       right |    center    |
| aligned          |     aligned |   aligned    |
```

When I "Markdown Preview" it just displays like this:

| | | Left align adsf | Right align | Center align | | --- | --- | ---------------- | ----------- | ------------ | | | | ---------------s | ----------- | ------------ | | --- | --- | :--------------- | ----------: | :----------: | | | | This | This | This | | | | column | column | column | | | | will | will | will | | | | be | be | be | | | | left | right | center | | | | aligned | aligned | aligned |

I have switched the file type to MultiMarkdown (lower right portion of ST2 screen)

I have searched, and it appears some people have a build system, or other approaches I have been unable to get going.   What am I missing?  If  a build system is needed, how do I set up one?  I am mainly interested in viewing this in HTML, but wouldn't be opposed to other ways....

Answer (score 2):

If you switch the parser to github, it'll work just fine.

Go to `Prefrences > Package Settings > Markdown Preview > Settings - User` and paste this code:

```
{
  "parser": "github"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"If a build system is needed, how do I set up one?"

In OS X I would strong suggest getting the excellent [Marked.app](http://markedapp.com) and then setting up a new build system in ST containing this trivial code

```
{
    "osx": {"cmd": ["open", "-a", "Marked", "$file"]},
    "selector": "text.html.markdown"
}
```

Then when you 'build' a markdown file (Cmd+B) you will get a preview generated in Marked.

Easy and elegant and well worth the cup-of-coffee price of Marked to avoid all the hassle of the plugin approach.